# Retrieving data from div element and submitting it with post using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Jquery and struggling to retrieve date values from my 'span' element in my jquery code and want to post it along with my form using java script.The reason i need to use this approach is that I am trying to use date range picker provided at http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/

I have no idea how can i embed my span element value to my form and post it other page along with other form data.

**Javscript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("btnsubmit").addEventListener("click", function () {
var s;
 s=jQuery.data($('aname'),s);

alert(s);

    document.form.submit();
  });

</script>
```

**FORM:**
    
       
            
              -

```
     <b class="caret"></b>
     <span><?php echo date("F j, Y", strtotime('-30 day')); ?> - <?php echo date("F j, Y"); ?> </span>
    </div>
     <button id="btnsubmit" onclick="document.getElementById('frmdate').submit();">submit</button>

  </form>
```

All i want to retrieve value of date from span element and post it along with form to retrieve it on next page to filter records from database based on this value.I would appreciate if anybody could help me in this regard.Thanks

Comment: That's a lovely mix of horrible code ?

Comment: @adeneo.Could u please expleain whats wrong with it?

Comment: Better start with some Jquery tutorials...

Comment: is there a reason you are keeping your data in a span rather than a hidden input field? Also, the span in question is not in the code you posted. Also `$('aname')` means you are looking for `<aname />` element.

Comment: @Ramy.Thanks.I have updated my code.I want to use bootstrap daterange picker as mentioned above.I have tried to use hidden value but once i change the date picker,the hidden field doesnt capture the latest value of datepicker.So just thought to capture the container of "span" element .Is there anyway to grab span container?

Comment: Hey user check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7JGSw/. And you might want to do this free course https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery

Comment: @Deceiver.Thanks for the link and fiddle.But the fiddle is just displaying alert on click event and not addressing the issue i am after!

Comment: i want to capture data from span element and post it along with form !

Answer (score 1):

As i suggested in the fiddle:

```
<form action="#">   
  <b class="caret"></b>
    <span>14-10-2014</span>
    <input type="hidden" name="tt" value="10-10-2014" />
    <input id="tt2"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
    <a href="#" id="submit">submit</a>
<form>
```

And for the java script:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($("input[name='tt']").val()+" - Method 1");
    $("#tt2").val($("span").text());
});

$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($("input[name='tt']").val() + " - Method 2");
    $("#tt2").val($("span").text());
});
```

Don't forget to add the Jquery script.
(In the edit i've included the copy from the span)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't followed your tutorial properly.
Here is some code from the tutorial, and you will notice it puts the data into an INPUT field which will then be automatically sent as the form data, no added jQuery needed.

```
<form id="frmdate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="reservation">Reservation dates:</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <input type="text" name="reservation" id="reservation" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reservation').daterangepicker();
});
</script>
```

Also in your code you've mixed jQuery and standard javascript badly.
For one you're listening for a click of the button rather than the submit of the form, this means your code will never execute if a enter hits Enter key and it submits the form without clicking the button. Moreover this is bad practice for that reasons alone (and many other reasons)

Here is a cleaned up version of your code:

```
<form id="frmdate">

    ...

    <b class="caret"></b>
    <span id="aname"><?php echo date("F j, Y", strtotime('-30 day')); ?> - <?php echo date("F j, Y"); ?></span>
    <button id="btnsubmit" type="sumbit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frmdate').submit(function(){
        // Do some code here.
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is how to submit form where values of datepicker is in span element NOT in input form element?:)

Comment: Span elements dont get send as form data without additional serialization code.
Even if the data is output _visually_ in a span, it must then be duplicated into an input. That input can be hidden so that the user is unaware of what is happened.